# how to edit this module to search book sets effectively?

Tags: python, set

i am practicing sets in python and wrote the below script to search books. it works but not proper ly(please see it below). How can i fix the problem?

```py
book_set = {"Harry Potter", "Angels and Demons", "Atlas Shrugged"}
q = input('Search our Catalog: ')
for book in book_set:
    if book == q:
        print(book)
else:
    print('sorry We ran out of this book')
```

my expected result should be the title of book if present and the strint('sorry We ran out of this book') if the book doesn't exists in book_set without any more results but see the example
enter code here

#### Output

```
Search our Catalog: Harry Potter
Harry Potter
sorry We ran out of this book
```

Comment: In Python, indentation is what defines the block of code. Use four spaces to indent, and ensure that the similar indents align. Your last print statement with 'Sorry... is aligned to the left of if, making it a separate block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` keyword instead of `for` loop:

```py
book_set = {"Harry Potter", "Angels and Demons", "Atlas Shrugged"}
q = input('Search our Catalog: ')
print("We have that book" if q in book_set "We don't have that book")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you are going through every book and if it is the book you print it but if it isn't you say you ran out, but for every single book. What you probably want to do is only say you ran out if the book isn't in the set which you can do by doing

```py
book_set = {"Harry Potter", "Angels and Demons", "Atlas Shrugged"}
q = input('Search our Catalog: ')
if q not in book_set:
    print("We don't have that book")
else:
    # code for when the book is in stock
```